# How do you truncate a `date` (not `timestamptz`) to month?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, timezone

Postgres has [`date_trunc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) which operates on `timestamp` or `interval`, and:

> Values of type date and time are cast automatically to timestamp or interval, respectively.

In other words we can use `date_trunc` for `date` values with a cast:

```
select date_trunc('month',current_date)::date;
┌────────────┐
│ date_trunc │
├────────────┤
│ 2014-12-01 │
└────────────┘
```

But is this timezone safe—if the current date is in Daylight Saving Time and the start of the month is not or vice versa will the correct date result?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's safe.

It's not exactly clear in the documentation but `date_trunc` can return either `timestamp` or `timestamptz` depending on what you pass it. If you pass a `date`, it will cast the input to `timestamp` and returns `timestamp` so there can be no tz issue when casting back to `date`.

If you pass a `timestamptz` it does the truncation the way you'd expect and returns a `timestamptz`:

```
select current_timestamp-'40d'::interval;
┌───────────────────────────────┐
│           ?column?            │
├───────────────────────────────┤
│ 2014-10-27 19:32:13.869909+00 │
└───────────────────────────────┘

select date_trunc('month',current_timestamp-'40d'::interval);
┌────────────────────────┐
│       date_trunc       │
├────────────────────────┤
│ 2014-10-01 00:00:00+01 │
└────────────────────────┘
```